# tabula.errors.JavaNotFoundError error while using tabula in Google cloud function

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-functions, tabula-py

For my application I am using the tabula package to convert the pdf to csv. The cloud function I have written is in python3.7. I have written it in requirements.txt file. But I am getting this error

```
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tabula/io.py", line 91, in _run raise JavaNotFoundError(JAVA_NOT_FOUND_ERROR) tabula.errors.JavaNotFoundError: `java` command is not found from this Python process.Please ensure Java is installed and PATH is set for `java`
```

**requirements file**

```
tabula-py==1.4.1
```

**main.py**

```
import tabula
df = tabula.read_pdf('/tmp/' + file_id +'.pdf', pages = required_page)[0]
tabula.convert_into('/tmp/' + file_id +'.pdf', '/tmp/' + file_id +'.csv',output_format="csv",pages=required_page, stream=False)
```

How do I resolve this? Is any alternative for this?

Comment: I also tried version 1.3.1, its causing the same error

Comment: I tried Camelot, but this needs Ghostscript.

Answer (score 2):

The error is expected since Java is not included in the [runtime image](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#runtimes) used by Google Cloud Functions Python3.7.

This means that is not possible to use this library within a Python Cloud Function as Java does not come in the [included system packages](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/system-packages).

However as an alternative, you could use [Google Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run) which is a more modern product that covers the same functionality that Cloud Functions. You can use this [Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/python) to deploy your first service and then install Java within your Dockerfile or use another Docker image that comes with Java installed.